# Unable to install operating system on a new workstation build

Tags: installation, windows-installation, bootable-media

I have recently completed a new workstation build. The motherboard is a supermicro M12SWA-TF that I purchased with a pre-installed AMD Threadripper Pro 3975WX processor.

The computer powers on fine. All case fans and the CPU cooler are functioning properly. The GPU works (output to screen during POST). USB works for keyboard because I'm able to navigate the BIOS configuration menu without any problem.

However, I'm unable to to install Windows 10 on the computer. I tried several ways (see below) and in each instance, the system either hangs (blank screen) or displays the UEFI shell.

First, I tried using the Windows 10 "Create Installation Media" tool to configure the installer on a USB key.

Second, I tried burning the Win 10 installer ISO to a DVD plugged in to a USB DVD drive.

Third, I tried booting from a SATA drive from another system that already has Windows 10 installed that I plugged into the new computer. This was mainly to test if anything different would happen. The two systems have different hardware so wasn't expecting everything to work perfectly. This still resulted in the UEFI shell being displayed.

Finally, I tried installing over network using PXE. I had never done this before. I followed a tutorial and used [Serva](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/). This was the most promising option. For once, the UEFI shell wasn't shown and the system showed a message saying that it had downloaded files successfully and displayed its IP address. On the host system (in the Serva Log), I could see the files that were downloaded. However, the log showed several errors (such as missing files). On the new system, probably because of the errors, the system would just hang after the initial success message. At no point did it display a GUI of the Windows installer.

I would look forward to any solution including:

1. An alternate means of installing Windows that I haven't tried.
2. Help with getting the PXE install to work.
3. Any diagnostic steps that I could execute that could help identify what's causing the problem.

Comment: does [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQS9A4O_4uQ) helps ?

Comment: Usually, Windows ISO on USB made with Windows media creation tool works. To check if it's a hardware issue vs. BIOS/UEFI setup, try a live USB with an*alternative* OS, e.g. Ubuntu. If that boots from USB (no need to install on your SSD/HDD), then you have working hardware and acceptable BIOS configuration... and if not, it needs to be fixed before installing Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The missing file errors mentioned when booting PXE with Serva are normal and not abortive. The install process requests policy files and the like that do not stop the install process when they are not present.

About your problem it looks like there might be a hardware or driver issue in your setup. Seeing a console does not tell you that the video system might not crash when moving to graphic mode if the proper driver is not included in the booted ISO.

If this is the case Serva will allow to include the driver or you might need to edit the corresponding Boot.wim and add the requiered drivers with Dism.exe